# value-of select in xslt 2.0

Tags: xslt-2.0

I am using xslt 2.0.
I am using value-of select and getting a concatenated string returned because of duplicate elements. I tried preceding-sibling and generate-id and neither would remove the second part of the string. How can I accomplish this?

output

2   11 Kenneth Street ***3755 Peachtree Road NE  (bold section from second element to be removed)***

```
    <xsl:value-of select="wd:Personal_Data/wd:Contact_Data/wd:Address_Data/wd:Address_Line_Data[@wd:Type='ADDRESS_LINE_1']"/>
```

xml

```
    <wd:Contact_Data>
                    <wd:Address_Data wd:Effective_Date="2000-01-01-08:00" wd:Address_Format_Type="Extended" wd:Formatted_Address="Av Cmte JÃºlio Moura, 900&amp;#xa;Barra de Tijuca&amp;#xa;Rio de Janeiro- RJ&amp;#xa;22621-252&amp;#xa;Brazil" wd:Defaulted_Business_Site_Address="0">
                       <wd:Country_Reference wd:Descriptor="Brazil">
                          <wd:ID wd:type="WID">1a29bb1357b240ab99a2fa755cc87c0e</wd:ID>
                          <wd:ID wd:type="ISO_3166-1_Alpha-2_Code">BR</wd:ID>
                          <wd:ID wd:type="ISO_3166-1_Alpha-3_Code">BRA</wd:ID>
                          <wd:ID wd:type="ISO_3166-1_Numeric-3_Code">76</wd:ID>
                       </wd:Country_Reference>
                       <wd:Last_Modified>2009-06-06T20:07:49.246-07:00</wd:Last_Modified>
                       <wd:Address_Line_Data wd:Type="ADDRESS_LINE_1" wd:Descriptor="Street Name">Av Cmte JÃºlio Moura</wd:Address_Line_Data>
                       <wd:Address_Line_Data wd:Type="ADDRESS_LINE_3" wd:Descriptor="House Number">900</wd:Address_Line_Data>
                       <wd:Municipality>Rio de Janeiro</wd:Municipality>
                       <wd:Submunicipality_Data>Barra de Tijuca</wd:Submunicipality_Data>
                       <wd:Country_Region_Reference wd:Descriptor="Rio de Janeiro">
                          <wd:ID wd:type="WID">e88c3d7cdb2b4a8b8120ede0b16e2186</wd:ID>
                          <wd:ID wd:type="Country_Region_ID">BRA-RJ</wd:ID>
                       </wd:Country_Region_Reference>
                       <wd:Postal_Code>22621-252</wd:Postal_Code>
                       <wd:Usage_Data wd:Public="0">
                          <wd:Type_Data wd:Primary="1">
                             <wd:Type_Reference wd:Descriptor="Home">
                                <wd:ID wd:type="WID">836cf00ef5974ac08b786079866c946f</wd:ID>
                                <wd:ID wd:type="Communication_Usage_Type_ID">HOME</wd:ID>
                             </wd:Type_Reference>
                          </wd:Type_Data>
                          <wd:Use_For_Reference wd:Descriptor="Street Address">
                             <wd:ID wd:type="WID">f785430145674364a613cd56086942c4</wd:ID>
                             <wd:ID wd:type="Communication_Usage_Behavior_ID">STREET</wd:ID>
                          </wd:Use_For_Reference>
                          <wd:Use_For_Reference wd:Descriptor="Mailing">
                             <wd:ID wd:type="WID">9385649a0c4b4ddea7fb0d823c2f1bcd</wd:ID>
                             <wd:ID wd:type="Communication_Usage_Behavior_ID">MAILING</wd:ID>
                          </wd:Use_For_Reference>
                       </wd:Usage_Data>
                    </wd:Address_Data>
                    <wd:Address_Data wd:Effective_Date="2000-01-01-08:00" wd:Address_Format_Type="Basic" wd:Formatted_Address="3755 Peachtree Road NE&amp;#xa;Atlanta, GA 30305&amp;#xa;United States of America" wd:Defaulted_Business_Site_Address="1">
                       <wd:Country_Reference wd:Descriptor="United States of America">
                          <wd:ID wd:type="WID">bc33aa3152ec42d4995f4791a106ed09</wd:ID>
                          <wd:ID wd:type="ISO_3166-1_Alpha-2_Code">US</wd:ID>
                          <wd:ID wd:type="ISO_3166-1_Alpha-3_Code">USA</wd:ID>
                          <wd:ID wd:type="ISO_3166-1_Numeric-3_Code">840</wd:ID>
                       </wd:Country_Reference>
                       <wd:Last_Modified>2011-06-20T13:54:02.466-07:00</wd:Last_Modified>
                       <wd:Address_Line_Data wd:Type="ADDRESS_LINE_1" wd:Descriptor="Address Line 1">3755 Peachtree Road NE</wd:Address_Line_Data>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to output the first selected element then use `<xsl:value-of select="(wd:Personal_Data/wd:Contact_Data/wd:Address_Data/wd:Address_Line_Data[@wd:Type='ADDRESS_LINE_1'])[1]"/>`.

Or based on the input you have shown I think `<xsl:value-of select="wd:Personal_Data/wd:Contact_Data/wd:Address_Data[1]/wd:Address_Line_Data[@wd:Type='ADDRESS_LINE_1']"/>` should also work.

Also note that you can use `version="1.0"` on your stylesheet with an XSLT 2.0 processor to indicate you are moving XSLT 1.0 to 2.0 but currently want XSLT 1.0 backwards compatible processing (such as outputting only the first selected node with `xsl:value-of`). That way you can adapt your code gradually.

Comment: The first line of code worked like a charm. Thank you Martin.